# How to put two videos side by side hiding the half of their width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm working in an app to compare videos and I have this use case. This is how it looks  [image: Two Videos view]

I've been trying with a custom view that extends of Relative Layout and putting the video views inside it, but I cannot achieve this result.

You must taking into account that the video width must be equals than the width of the screen because when someone taps some of the videos, it must be translated until it is totally visible. I think that the left video should be translated to the left by half of the width screen and the same logic must be applied to the right video.

Comment: Pls post some code.

Comment: Also the details of the result you are getting.

Comment: Use weight sum.

Answer (score 1):

I could it do that with the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/right_video"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/left_video"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Programmatically, in the onCreate of the activity I request for the width of the screen and make the translation in X axis. This looks like:

```
    Point screenDimens = ViewUtils.getScreenDimensions(this);
    int videoSize = screenDimens.x;
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) leftVideo.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = videoSize;
    params.height = videoSize;
    leftVideo.setLayoutParams(params);
    rigthVideo.setLayoutParams(params);
    leftVideo.setTranslationX(-videoSize / 2);
    rigthVideo.setTranslationX(videoSize / 2);
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am putting one sample you may try this, Inside the **LinearLayout** you can place your **videoview** which u r using for playing video

**activty_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create landscape linear layout and put inside two views(SurfaceView or TextureView or GlSurfaceView). And give these views the weight equal to 1. It will be like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" >

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/double1_texture_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/double2_texture_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The best sample to see is [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/DoubleDecodeActivity.java).
But if you want to ***compare videos***, then do not forget that one of the videos should be cropped for example. Because you need to compare left side of one video with left side of another video. And do not forget about aspect ratio.

Comment: But in this case how do you handle the translation of the video when someone taps on it?

Comment: You will not achieve this with just correct layout. To make translation and crop, you should use GL commands and GlSurfaceView.

Comment: I can achieve animations using Object Animator. Here you can read more about this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views

Comment: Totally not sure about this method. Look, for example you have one view(with surface) on which video will be rendered. You can not move half of this view beyond the screen of the device because you just want to show half of video.